# Finding substring at the end of line in shell

Tags: android, regex, bash, shell, grep

I am new to shell scripting.

When I write 
`adb shell ps | grep "org.mozilla.fennec"`
I get

```
u0_a52    908   57    557664 144820 ffffffff b6f755cc S org.mozilla.fennec
```

and

```
u0_a52    1083  57    243108 23824 ffffffff b6f755cc S org.mozilla.fennec.UpdateService
```

The problem is I only need the first line. So I tried with `adb shell ps | grep "org.mozilla.fennec$"` but surprisingly it shows nothing.

I will also need the second field of the first line. How can I do this using grep?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print 2nd field you can use `awk`:

```
adb shell ps | awk -v RS='\r' '$NF == "org.mozilla.fennec"{print $2}'
```

To print whole line:

```
adb shell ps | awk -v RS='\r' '$NF == "org.mozilla.fennec"'
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure why it's not working . Anyway, the second answer is working.

Comment: That should work. What does `adb shell ps | cat -vte` show to you?

Comment: it prints information for all the processes.. one example line is:                    u0_a52    908   57    557664 144912 ffffffff b6f755cc S org.mozilla.fennec^M$

Comment: Ah it is due to `^M` or `\r` before line end. I have updated the awk command. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To remove second line:

```
adb shell ps | grep "org.mozilla.fennec"|grep -v "UpdateService"
```

To print second field:

```
adb shell ps | grep "org.mozilla.fennec"|grep -v "UpdateService"| awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: make sure your grep actually defaults to having regexes turned on. if not, `$` will just be a dollar sign, not an end-of-string marker..

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you please tell me how to take only the second field from here?

Comment: Got it.. | awk 'print $2'

Comment: 2 `grep` and 1 `awk`, this is really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The below command will look first occurrence of org.mozilla.fennec in command output of "adb shell ps" and will stop looking after that.

```
adb shell ps |  awk '{if($0~/org.mozilla.fennec/){print $2; exit 0}}'
```

Its better when you need the first pattern match, don't need to scan whole output after first match.